# Is Monodevelop a good compiler for game development in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is Monodevelop a good compiler for game development in unity? 
I am very interested in game development. It is the default [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) compiler and I want to know some other best compiler for unity.

Comment: Hi Vishal while an interesting question, it's NOT suitable for this site unfortunately. Try forum.unity3d, gamedev, or similar.  Mono is just a text editor, it makes no difference.  The handful of top, most famous Unity engineers only use "Notepad" as a text editor, if you have to use Windows. Don't hesitate to ask more questions here when you have any questions that are suitable for this site (actual questions *about code*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monodevelop isn't a compiler, it's an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).  The compiler for Unity projects is the Mono compiler, and that remains constant regardless of the text editor you use to edit the source.

I would say "no" it's not a good editor as using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition is better if you run Windows and using Visual Studio Code is better if you run OSX.

Comment: Hi Troj.  There is a huge problem w/ low quality questions in `Unity3D` tag. It's perhaps better not to answer such questions, just click "Close" on 'em

Comment: @JoeBlow I know.  I just could not help myself from answering.  I knew it was wrong as well.